Creating a 12.6 V 3S Lithium-ion Charging Circuit from 5 V USB-C
I have some questions about what is considered standard for a charging circuit, as this is something I have not much experience in. I am constrained to the following:

3S lithium-ion battery of 2600 mAh charging at 1 A,
USB-C connector with 5 V,
the BMS is already included with the battery.

My main question is if this solution will work and if this is the best way to handle charging given the constraints. Everything seems to check out with the Boost circuit and charger spec sheets. I couldn't find many 3S reference designs online which use a proper charger, but perhaps I didn't know where to look.
The charger in use is the SLM6900, which has this store. The translated datasheet is here.
My board will flow as follows:
           USB-C ⇾ 5 V to 12.6 V boost circuit ⇾ 3S charging circuit --> battery

Here is the 5V ⇾ 12.6 V boost schematic

Here is the 3S charger circuit

Below is the full schematic

Another option I found is this product SLM6803. This is capable of doing all that I described above, which is that it works as a boost circuit for 5 V and will ALSO charge a 3S battery. Here is the store link and here is the translated datasheet.

There just aren't any reference designs online for it, so there is some uncertainty, but it seems to be the perfect solution unless I misunderstood something.

I plan to order circuit for both the SLM6900 (the main schematic above) and the SLM6803, so I have a backup option.

If you want to charge a 3S battery with 1A to 12.6V, you need more than 2.5A of 5V. Not really going to happen as you do not know how much 5V your circuit can draw. Maybe 900mA tops, but you are neither negotiating anything or detecting how much current is available

@Justme I see now, because the power would be insufficient. And I would say the 1A current draw is the most flexible requirement, so I’m okay even if it’s half of that.
Considering that, is it likely the circuit will still function? (Albeit, at a lower charge rate)

No it would not even be half of 1A. And no it won't function if you forcibly try to pull current out of a port that can't supply it, it likely detects overcurrent and shuts down.

I would recommend looking into the CN3303. If you're patient with the chinese datasheet (chrome has a translation feature) it shows you a recommended design and even gives component recommendations based on what speed you want to charge at. Very few components, nice simple design, some cool features. There's a cheap little module on amazon, ebay etc if you want to try it out. Just type in someti "3S USB-C li-ion battery charger module" and it's the green rectangular one.
